# Can't get jupyter notebook to work for python 3.8

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

Hey so I was able to get Jupiter notebook working on python 3.75 with no issues, but when I try to "pip install notebook" to better see pandas data on python 3.8 I get this error:

```
Collecting pywin32>=1.0; sys_platform == "win32" (from jupyter-core>=4.6.1->notebook)
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pywin32>=1.0; sys_platform == "win32" (from jupyter-core>=4.6.1->notebook) (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for pywin32>=1.0; sys_platform == "win32" (from jupyter-core>=4.6.1->notebook)
```

Other solutions I have tried to find online are fairly vague and I have yet to find someone with the exact problem. Do you guys/girls have any suggestions?

Comment: What about installing Anaconda, or creating a new conda env for 3.8?  If you use the `anaconda` directive on the new env, it'll install Jupyter (iPython) as part of the bundle.  Is there a pressing need to upgrade to 3.8?  (IMHO it's immature yet.)

Comment: Was the incompatibility between 3.8+ and Tornado fixed? I'm still on 3.7 because last time I checked 3.8 couldn't be used with Jupyter at all, but that was months ago.

Comment: I am fairly new to data stuff, but according to what I could find, there were some incompatibilities figured out, but I'm not sure if it is all of them. I am quite unfamiliar with Anaconda, but I will check it out. There's not really a pressing need, just don't want to restart my project with a new venv lol, I might as well though. Thanks for the help yal!